# Are different Jupyter Notebooks automatically run in parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know whether, when I run multiple Jupyter Notebooks (different files) simultaneously, they are automatically distributed over multiple cores? Or are they by default threaded on a single core? I am not explicitly using a multiprocessing package of any kind and not looking for a way to implement parallel computing. I'm just curious whether the computer automatically sends the calculations to different cores.

Comment: Have you tried searching online? I got helpful search results easily, one of which was a [link to the docs](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and also [these docs](https://curc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gateways/parallel-programming-jupyter.html).

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't phrase my question clearly enough. The question is not how to implement parallel computing, but if I run one notebook and simultaneously another one, does the computer automatically distribute the two notebooks over two different cores?